# spend child contract(deployed by mother contract) from mother contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, create2

I have created a smart contract like this :

```
contract ChildContract {

   function sendTokenTo(uint _amount, ITRC20 _token, address payable _receiver) external payable onlyOwner {
       
        _token.transfer(_receiver,  _amount);
    }
    receive() external payable {}
}

contract mainContract {

  function deploy_child_in_token_mode(uint _uuid, ITRC20 _token, uint _amount, address payable _receiver) external {

address a =  address(new ChildContract{salt: bytes32(_uuid)}(msg.sender)); // to generate a smart contract with create2 method!
ChildContract(payable(a)).sendTokenTo(_amount, _token, _receiver);

}
```

but it's too expensive.
Is there any way transfer child assets from main contract?

something like this?:

```
contract ChildContract {

    receive() external payable {}

   function returnSomethingFromThisChild{
   }

}

contract mainContract {

  function deploy_child_in_token_mode(uint _uuid, ITRC20 _token, uint _amount, address payable _receiver) external {

address a =  address(new ChildContract{salt: bytes32(_uuid)}(msg.sender)); // to generate a smart contract with create2 method!
objectOfChild = perChildInstance.returnSomethingFromThisChild();

        objectOfChild._token.transfer(_receiver,  _amount);
}
```

I mean get back control of flow to main contract and main contract transfer any asset of child contract.

is there any way to this?
Or if you know any low gas way to do this.

Comment: Why are you deploying a new child every time you need to make a transfer?

Comment: @0xSanson I have many user, I develop a contract for each user